# Dropdown data not being sent to $_POST php

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm new to coding, and have encountered some difficulty with the drop-down list. Would appreciate any help given!

I have this:

```
<html>
    <select name="Subject">
    <option value="One">One</option>
    <option value="Two">Two</option>
    </select>
</html>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    echo $_POST['Subject']; 
}
echo '
<form method="post"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Option!"></form>';
?>
```

This returns me with an unidentified index error for 'Subject' whenever I hit the Submit Option button.
I did a `print_r($_POST)` and realized that my selected options for the drop-down list "Subject" did not pass through. (i.e. The `$_POST` array that was printed did not show anything selected options from the drop-down list)

Comment: You need to create form before dropdowns and `end` it after markup.

Comment: Your `<select>...</select>` isn't inside the `<form>...</form>` tags.

Comment: may i know how this <form> should be added? :)

Comment: Stop coding both the form and the processing logic in a single file. That is plain stupid. Yes, I know, many introductions do that. But it simply does not make any sense. It only confuses.

Comment: your `<select>` should be inside of the `<form>..</form>` tag so if you are using forms start the `<form>`tag right after the `<body>`tag

Comment: If you ever plan to submit the form using script, you should rename the button, otherwise `<form>.submit()` will fail (where <form> is whatever you do to get the form object)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To submit your selected value to PHP you need to put `<select>` inside `<form>` code like below:-

```
<html>
    <form method="post">
    
    <select name="Subject">
    <option value="One">One</option>
    <option value="Two">Two</option>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Option!"></form>
</html>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['Subject'])){
echo $_POST['Subject']; 
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback, I will be trying these out :)

Comment: Yup, it worked well. Thanks for all the help, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 3):

One of the first things to know about HTML forms is that, when a form is submitted, the information contained *within it* gets submitted. To submit a value for Subject, that field needs to be contained within the `<form>` element.

```
<html>
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        echo $_POST['Subject']; 
    }
    ?>
    <form method="post">
        <select name="Subject">
            <option value="One">One</option>
            <option value="Two">Two</option>
        </select>

        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Option!">
    </form>
</html>
```

Comment: and change the name of the submit button in case you ever want to use script to submit it

Comment: @mplungjan You'd use an ID then, not its name.

Comment: Let's stick with basics first, @mplungjan :) Besides, `document.querySelector('input[name="submit"]').click()` would still submit this form!

Comment: The more logical `document.getElementById("myForm").submit()` will fail! and so will `document.querySelector("#myForm").submit()` and you will scratch your head